# Triple dot notation not working in js local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Triple dot notation is not working in local storage of Google Chrome.
I'm trying to add the object to existing object but it is not working.

```js
let incomes = localStorage.getItem("Incomes");
incomes = JSON.parse(incomes);

let data = {
  capital: capital,
  name: name,
  price: price
}

if (incomes) {
  incomes = {
    ...incomes,
    income: data,
  }
} else {
  incomes = {
    income: data,
  }
}

localStorage.setItem("Incomes", JSON.stringify(incomes));
```

Comment: What does `incomes` look like before? What is the expected result? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] mocking the localstorage (it is not allowed in snippets)

Comment: My wild guess is that incomes is null and so it goes in the else block.

Comment: Firstly,I sent  the data i fetched from input field in html to "data" object then  also saved to local storage and it was saved to local storage but when i try to save another data to local storage it overrides previous.

Comment: I just want to save multiple data (multiple objects) in local storage in the same object ie. incomes objects.

Comment: Before incomes was an object which was saved in local storage

Answer (score 0):

Please add default value to income

```
incomes = JSON.parse(incomes) || {};
```

Comment: Remove the first semi-colon.